# How to handle event of MainWindow in one of the ViewModel which belongs to a View, but not MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I wanted to handle MainWindow's **Closing** event in one of my ViewModel. This ViewModel belongs to a View which is displayed on top of the MainWindow. I wanted to save values of some properties present in that ViewModel while/before closing of the application.

I am using MvvmCross to implement MVVM pattern. So I tried overriding **ViewDisappearing**, **ViewDisappeared** and **ViewDestroy** methods, but they are only getting called when View get switched, but not when application/window closes.

While searching for this requirement, I could only find this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/477e7e74-ccbf-4498-8ab9-ca2f3b836597/how-to-know-when-a-wpf-usercontrol-is-closing?forum=wpf , which is close to my requirement, but needs to be implemented in code-behind.

Can anyone please help me in achieving this in MVVM/MvvmCross in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

I had some experience to implement events by `MVVM` maybe it can help you.
As I know there is a package on [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf) that will help to get the events and execute a command

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"    
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosingWindow}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and if you want to execute a command in other view models you can use a static command

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views.Windows"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"    
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:static local:ViewModel.ClosingWindow}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Yes, I know about **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf**, but problem is View(MvxWpfView) is inherited from UserControl, and UserControl doesn't have event **Closing**.

Comment: And as suggested by you to use static command, I m not clear how to implement that, as I declared my ViewModel Folder's xmlns in MainWindow `xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:DummyApp.ViewModels"`, but  `<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:static VM:View1ViewModel.ClosingWindowCommand}"/>` gives me error.

Comment: you said "MainWindow's Closing event" so I wrote an example for that. whatever see the event [Application Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.exit?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).
And about static `Command` you just need to declare a static `ICommand` property in your `ViewModel` filled by `Action` and addressed it in XAML